# Value conversion issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have the following issue:

```
implicit conversion loses integer precision 'unsigned long' to 'int'
```

for the following code

```
int arraySize = (bits + bitsPerWord_ - 1) >> logBits_;
```

What should I do to fix it, it only started in xcode 5.1

Comment: The issue was there all along, it was just that the warning was on by default in Xcode 5.1

Comment: It's an error not warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your variables is `unsigned long` (eg. NSUInteger). I'd suggest using `NSInteger` instead, if possible. Other solution is to cast the variable in question to `NSInteger`.

```
NSInteger arraySize = ((NSInteger)bits + (NSInteger)bitsPerWord_ - 1) >> logBits_;
```

As for the error you get, you might have compiler setting to treat this kind of warning as an error.

Comment: Just compiling works but when I archive it I get this error.  Tried everything won't go away.

Comment: What are the types of each variable (bits, bitsPerWord_, logBits_)?

Comment: It was a hidden compiler issue.  Thanks

Comment: A setting in "other warning flags" for future problems anyone encounters.